Zip files don't show up when opening VSCode parent folder?
If I open VSCode on the folder that contains a zip file the zip file is visible.
So for example:
code parent/folder-containing-zip

If I look in the explorer view it shows zip files in the folder-containing-zip.  However if I just open the parent folder like this:
code parent

And toggle/expand the folder-containing-zip the zip files are not visible in the view ( Other code files are though ...).
Any way to fix this?

@starball - Hm - Funny you mention that - because I was about to say no ... and when I look there is one.  And it has a files.exclude property that  excluded the zip files and some other files I was looking for.  Strange, because I did not create this file ...

Resolution via comments.  The .vscode/settings.json file in the parent folder excluded zip files.
